# What is the importance of independent increment in stochastic processes?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

What is the importance of independent increment in stochastic processes?

What would "break" if independent increment property is not valid?

Comment: Question is vague.   Independence may be required for a particular theorem.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. Please explain in more detail what yu are interested in. Independence of increments is e.g. crucial for the Markov property